# User Defined Java Multiplication Table using Two Class Files

Tags: java

I need to create two class files for creating a multiplication table based upon what size the user specifies (<=15) and use the following for the assignment. I was on Thanksgiving Break and was not able to retrieve the instructions for creating the two classes so I wrote one program that prompts the user and now I am not sure how I can break that into two classes. One class is the Table, which specifies the table size and the other class is the Table App. Here are the instructions that I didn't have access to:

The smallest allowed table size is a 2x2 table; and the largest is a 15x15 table. The number of rows and columns will always be the same (i.e., the program won't create a 5x10 table).
It won't let me post a picture here but the table goes from 1 to 15 along the column headers which are separated by dashes. Then the row header is separated by dashes as it goes from 1 to 15

The number in each cell of the table is the product of the column heading above it, and the row label to its left. All of the numbers should be right-justified.

The table shall be generated by a class named Table. This class can consist of as many methods as you feel it appropriate to create, but must include at least the following:

(constructor)--Takes one input parameter: the size of the table. Valid values range from 2 to 15 (inclusive).
print---No input parameters and no return value. This is the method that will display the multiplication table.
printLine---Takes one input parameter: the number of dashes to print in line form. This is a helper method that you'll use from the print method. It is for creating the three horizontal lines in the table.

Without having the instructions I wrote the code to make the table a variable size and width based on the user input and did not make it inclusive to 2 to 15. I am still very new to Java and I was very proud of the code I wrote until I was able to get to the internet and see the instructions. 
This is the code that I wrote and it creates the table but I can't get the dashes perfect like the picture and I did not create two class files..I just wrote it in one. Can someone please help me??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table {
    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How big is the table: ");

        int size = s.nextInt();
        int formatStringLength = Integer.toString(size*size).length();
        int axesFormatStringLength = Integer.toString(size).length();
        String formatString = String.format("%%%ds", formatStringLength);
        String axesFormatString = String.format("%%%ds",
                axesFormatStringLength);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("* | ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
        {
            //System.out.print(i + " ");
            System.out.printf(formatString + " ", i);
        }

        System.out.print("\n----");

        //for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
        for (int i = 1; i <= size*formatStringLength; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("--");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            System.out.printf(axesFormatString + " | ", i);

            for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {

                System.out.printf(formatString + " ", i * j);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really follow instruction and make two classes. You need to create a class named `Table` then create a runnable application class to run use the `Table` class

**Table.java**

```
public class Table{
    private int size;

    // constructor
    public Table(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public void print(){
        // do some printing

        printline(20);

        // do some more printing

        printline(20);

        // do some more printing

        printline(20);

        // do some more printing

    }

    public void printLine(int dashes){
        // loop to print number of dashes
    }
}
```

**TestTable.java**  Example run

```
public class TextTable{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // create an instance of Table
        Table table = new Table(5);

        // print table
        table.print();
    }
}
```

This is a basic outline/template of what your code should look like, as per the instructions.